# Laravel's Auth::user() returns null

Tags: php, laravel, module

I changed my Laravel file structure like this
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCLiS.png).

I won't discuss how cause it's long but everything works fine and now if I want to access the **Auth**::user() or anything from **Auth** from the new Controllers, Views or Models locations it returns **errors or null**, and when i access the **Auth** from the **routes/web.php** it works fine so something in my **new configuration** is missing any ideas how to fix it? any file code is needed just ask me to put it, Thanks.

Comment: `web.php` has the `web` group of middleware applied from the RouteServiceProvider which provides sessions.  Would need to see what you are actually doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question to show the image directly instead of as a link. Please also show the errors you're getting, preferably as text.

Comment: am just dividing my application file structure into modules so each module has its own controllers models views file structure

Comment: sorry am just new here and am not allowed to put pictures directly...need more XPs

Comment: ok so from the User/Views/profile.blade.php if i access Auth::user() it returns null same with controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx for the "hint" [@lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) gave me but i figured it out.
i just needed to add the web middleware the the route in my User/routes.php like so:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\User\Controllers'], function(){
    Route::get('/profile', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UsersController@profile'])->middleware('web');
           );
```